# How do I show and position an Image initialized in the codebehind on my page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, controls, methods

I have created a simple method to check if an image has been approved and finally returns it as an control. But how do i call and show it on the page? I've tried something like this in the aspx-file:

```
<% SendImage("DKBygMiniLogo.gif", "True"); %>
```

Here is the simple method:

```
protected Image SendImage(object Image, object Approved)
{
  bool approved = Convert.ToBoolean(Approved);
  Image img = new Image();
  if (approved)
  {
      img.ImageUrl = "~/images/Ads/" + Image.ToString();
      img.Visible = true;
  }
  else
  {
      img.ImageUrl = "~/images/Ads/" + Image.ToString();
      img.Visible = false;
  }
   return img;
}
```

How do I actually show the image?

Comment: Can you please explain a little more about what you are trying to do as I don't think I understand your need for this. Why not just place the image control directly on the page and access it in page load (or a handler) and identify if the image is approved and hide and set the visiblity to true of false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You could quite easily attach the result of `SendImage` to a literal control.</strike>

In your C# code:

```
Image myShinyNewImage = SendImage(someImageObject, approved);
myLiteralControl.Controls.Add(myShinyNewImage);
```

In your aspx page:

```
<asp:Literal id="myLiteralControl" runat="server" />
```

**UPDATE:**

As correctly pointed out in the comments, you can't add child controls to a Literal however you can add the control directly to the page.

```
this.Controls.Add(SendImage(someImageObject, approved));
```

or add the control to another control that does allow child controls to be added such as a Panel control.

Comment: Thanks. So adding it to a asp:Panel would be a possibility?